# How do I use Moq to mock an interface that has methods that take concrete classes as parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

1. I have this scenario: an interface with 2 methods
2. the 2 methods take requests and return response
3. Methods contain functionality inside (check permissions and validate request and get data from database using entity framework.
4. But I want to test the methods and not just the interface.
5. I've tested the interface successfully but now I want to enter the method and test inside it.

Code example:

```
 public interface IMyInterface
    {
      [OperationContract]
      responseObject GetData(Service<RequestObject> request);
    }

    public class MyConcreteClass : IMyInterface
    {
       public responseObject GetData(Service<RequestObject> request)
       {
          CheckForNull(request);
          ValidateMethod(request);
          //connect to db
          using(var context = new contextEntity)
          {
            //get data
          }
       }
    }
```

Now, I want to test the check nulls, permissions and data access, is it possible? Or do I have to extract interface from the internal methods?

PS, this is for my unit testing. I'm trying to eliminate external dependencies.
please explain in detail

Comment: Does Service<RequestObject> have any dependencies that you try to avoid?  If so, then yes, you need to make some interfaces to hide these dependencies behind.  Anyway, are you talking about compile time dependencies, or run-time dependencies (the former might not be a problem when unit testing)?

Comment: Yes, I don't want it to go to the db or authenticate.

Comment: Example I've seen takes an interface in the GetData method so when you mock the interface, it works but in my case I'm taking a generic class.

Comment: You can certainly make generic interfaces in C#.  Is either Service or RequestObject your own class?  If so, making an interface would be simple.  If not, you should wrap them with thin adapters having an interface, to revert the direction of the dependencies against the flow of control.

Comment: Service<RequestObject> this is an external dll so I have no control over this class, that is the challenge.

Comment: Adapters it is then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing private methods should not be needed directly, only indirectly via public methods. If you think you testing a public method isn't enough precise, it might be that the method and the class are too complicated already.

In that case consider creating one or more new classes where the new code is located. That way you can unit test your code via public method. The added benefit is that your code is probably better in terms of [Single responsibility principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: single responsibility principle was followed, but before going to db I validate the request then check if user has permissions to even pull data then pull data.

Comment: Same applies, consider making perhaps 3 classes that does each of those things and unit test each one. If not, make sure you cover all those cases in unit tests for one class (if that's your goal).

Comment: How can I wrap this parameter? Service<RequestObject> this is my main issue.if I was taking something like GetData(IService<RequestObject>) but I don't have access to the classes. That means I would have to wrap Service<RequestObject> which will basically put me in square one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for mocking is so that you can control behaviour; in this case, I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `Service<RequestObject>` doesn't actually have any behaviour, and therefore it doesn't actually *need* to be mocked. So it can probably just be passed as-is in any tests.

However, if it *does* have behaviour, and that behaviour crosses an architectural boundary (let's say in the `GetData` method you are calling some method on the `request` parameter that will make a network call, or access the file system, etc.) then you do need to mock it. But you can do that easily enough:

```
public interface IService<RequestObject>
{
   //put method and property signatures of Service<RequestObject> here
}

public class ServiceObject:Service<RequestObject>, IService<RequestObject>
{
   public ServiceObject(RequestObject request): base(request){
        //or however the Service<Request> object is instantiated.
   };
}
```

Then change `GetData` to take an `IService<RequestObject>`; now your calling code can instantiate a `ServiceObject` in place of a Service and pass it to the `GetData` method. Plus you can Mock any methods on the interface as you need. Obviously if you don't control the calling code, that's a problem since whoever is writing that code needs to do it, but that's a conversation you will need to have with them :)

In terms of testing the internal operations,you need to look at how you can abstract any dependent behaviours used by the `GetData` method - for example, the `contextEntity`, the `CheckForNull`, the `ValidateMethod`, etc - all of these are candidates to be extracted into their own abstractions and [injected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) into the `MyConcreteClass` as dependencies, e.g.:

```
public class MyConcreteClass: IMyInterface
{
   readonly INullChecker _nullChecker;
   readonly IValidator _validator;
   readonly IContextEntity _context;

   public MyConcreteClass(INullChecker nullChecker, IValidator validator, IContextEntity _context)
   {
      _nullChecker = nullChecker;
      _validator = validator;
      _context=context;
   }

   public responseObject GetData(Service<RequestObject> request)
   {
       _nullChecker.Check(request)//**;
       _validator.Validate(request);
       var result = _context.DoSomethingWith(request);
       return result;
   }
}
```

Now you can write tests for `MyConcreteClass` and use mocked implementations of the dependencies, to ensure that the GetData method correctly uses them.

**and I will guess that this can be replaced with a simple `if request==null throw new ArgumentNullException()` which is cleaner and simpler anyway.

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed answer. I ended up instantiating the concrete class then passing it a mocked object.

Comment: Super, that sounds like the best way to do it.